# str_split returning two chars

Tags: php, char

I wrote a function for safe link which is returning a string. The function is called safe_link(*string*), but I'm having a problem with the char replacement. I don't know why str_replace() isn't working, this is why I wrote my own function. I need to save a valid URL, I need to delete **http://**, **www.** from a string which is given in a form.

```
function safe_link($arg){
    $url = str_split($arg);
    $string = array();
    $max = 0;

    if($url[0] == "h" && $url[7] == "w") # http://www.
        $max = 11;
    elseif($url[0] == "h") # http://
        $max = 7;
    elseif($url[0] == "w") # www.
        $max = 4;

    str_replace("/", "", $url);

    for($i = $max, $n = 0; $i < sizeof($url); $i++, $n++){
        $string[$n] = $url[$i];
    }

    return implode("", $string);
}
```

The function is working, but what if a person wrote a "/" (slash) on the end of the URL? I need to delete from that string, but I don't know how to do it. str_replace() is not working. I tried to debug, and I saw that array `$url[sizeof($url) - 1]` is returning two characters instead of one char. But why?

Thank you !

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is a "function for safe link"?

Comment: $url is an array, str_replace is for strings

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to do.  Have a look at [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: I'd go with what @AleksG has posted ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about this function:

```
function safe_link($url) {
    $url = str_replace('http://', '', $url);
    $url = str_replace('www.', '', $url);
    $url = str_replace('/', '', $url);
    return trim($url);
}
```

Is this what do You expect?